# Get raw buffer for in-memory dataset in GDAL C++ API

Tags: c++, memory, gis, gdal

I have generated a GeoTiff dataset in-memory using `GDALTranslate()` with a `/vsimem/` filepath. I need access to the buffer for the actual GeoTiff file to put it in a stream for an external API. My understanding is that this should be possible with `VSIGetMemFileBuffer()`, however I can't seem to get this to return anything other than `nullptr`.

My code is essentially as follows:

```
//^^ GDALDataset* srcDataset created somewhere up here ^^
//psOptions struct has "-b 4" and "-of GTiff" settings.
const char* filep = "/vsimem/foo.tif";
GDALDataset* gtiffData = GDALTranslate(filep, srcDataset, psOptions, nullptr);

vsi_l_offset size = 0;
GByte* buf = VSIGetMemFileBuffer(filep, &size, true); //<-- returns nullptr
```

`gtiffData` seems to be a real dataset on inspection, it has all the appropriate properties (number of bands, raster size, etc). When I provide a real filesystem location to `GDALTranslate()` rather than the `/vsimem/` path and load it up in QGIS it renders correctly too.

Looking a the source for `VSIGetMemFileBuffer()`, this should really only be returning `nullptr` if the file can't be found. This suggests i'm using it incorrectly. Does anyone know what the correct usage is?

Bonus points: Is there a better way to do this (stream the file out)?

Thanks!

Comment: Try running your program with the environment variable `CPL_DEBUG ` set to `ON`. Everything you are doing looks ok to me. Maybe the `GDALTranslate` is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this after putting in a workaround, and upon swapping things back over it seems to work fine. @mmomtchev suggested looking at the `CPL_DEBUG` output, which showed nothing unusual (and was silent during the actual `VSIGetMemFileBuffer` call).

In particular, for other reasons I had to put a `GDALWarp` call in between calling `GDALTranslate` and accessing the buffer, and it seems that this is what makes the difference. My guess is that `GDALWarp` is calling `VSIFOpenL` internally - although I can't find this in the source - and this does some kind of initialisation for `VSIGetMemFileBuffer`. Something to try for anyone else who encounters this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the C++ API. But in Python, the snippet below is what I sometimes use to get the contents of an in-mem file. In my case mainly VRT's but it shouldn't be any different for other formats.

But as said, I don't know if the VSI-api translate 1-on-1 to C++.

```py
from osgeo import gdal

filep = "/vsimem/foo.tif"

# get the file size
stat = gdal.VSIStatL(filep, gdal.VSI_STAT_SIZE_FLAG)

# open file
vsifile = gdal.VSIFOpenL(filep, 'r')

# read entire contents
vsimem_content = gdal.VSIFReadL(1, stat.size, vsifile)
```

In the case of a VRT the content would be text, shown with something like `print(vsimem_content.decode())`. For a tiff it would of course be binary data.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. The docs suggest `VSIFOpenL()` won't let you leave the GDAL/VSI system:

"the “VSILFILE\*” returned by this function is NOT a standard C library FILE *, and cannot be used with any functions other than the “VSI\*L” family of functions. They aren’t “real” FILE objects."